# Do Catholics consider Catholic Church as a heresy of the Orthodox church?

Tags: catholicism, eastern-orthodox, heresy

A succession of ecclesiastical differences and theological disputes between the Greek Eastern Church and Latin West Church pre-dated the formal rupture that occurred in 1054. Prominent among these were the issues of the procession of the Holy Spirit, whether leavened or unleavened bread should be used in the Eucharist, the Bishop of Rome's claim to universal jurisdiction, and the place of the See of Constantinople in relation to the Pentarchy.

In 1053, the first step was taken in the process which led to formal schism.

Source: [East–West Schism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/East%E2%80%93West_Schism)

As far as I know, Catholisicm is an heresy of the Orthodox Church according to the Orthodoxs. Does the Catholic Church accept itself as an heresy?

Extending the question: Do heresies accept the term heresy when describe  themselves?

Comment: Have you read any Catholic writing on this?  Suggest the Council of Trent as a starting point ...

Comment: No one wants to be called a heretic, so why do you think the Catholic church would want to be called heretical?

Comment: "Heretical" means, among other things, wrong. Do you think the Catholic Church considers themselves wrong?

Comment: Anything which accepted itself as heretical cannot exist as a tenet of faith, rather by definition.

Comment: To be honest, I believe every single denomination believes they are right and others are in error. It is the way of human nature. What makes Catholicism different? If I thought the the Church was heretical, it would not make sense to remain a practicing  Catholic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do Catholics consider Catholic Church as a [heresy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heresy) of the Orthodox church?**

The short answer is **no**.

Been a Catholic all my life and I have never heard or read about a practicing Catholic makes such a bizarre claim against the Catholic Church. In fact, no teaching from the Popes or the Teaching Magisterium of the Catholic Church has ever been forthcoming.

Individuals may be sinful within the Church, but her doctrine is sound!

In fact the opposite is true. The Catholic Church possesses the fullness of true.

***The truth shall set us free!*** [(John 8:32)](https://biblehub.com/john/8-32.htm)

> **Truth does not change**. The amplitude, however, of what remains to be definitively true is always latently deficient. It is possible either to elicit more (analytically) from the truth we possess, or to acquire (historically) further dimensions of the truth yet to be predicated of it subsequent to the present.
>
> Simply put, we never possess the entirety of truth about anything whatever. More can always be predicated of it — with the sole (logical) stipulation that what furthermore can be said of it can be neither ***inconsistent with*** nor ***contradictory to*** it.
>
> This is not to say that what we hold to be true is inherently defective; what is presently true will always be true and will never cease to be true; it is merely incomplete relative to all truthful statements than can and will be predicated of it, such that what is true of it is exhaustively and definitively stated about it —  ***and nothing further truthful can be stated relative to it***. The complete truth about any existent encompasses too many aspects to be exhausted for the simple reason that its existence in time will never be totally enacted **until the end of time** — and more can predicated of anything ... than what is predicable of it at this moment in time and in moments past.
>
> This does not mean that what is true will ever cease to be true — **we cannot abolish what is true, nor will what is true ever be *not-true***. The totality of the truth pertaining to anything created only obtains in that final and definitive facticity beyond which nothing further can be stated about it in both time and place. What remains to be truthfully stated about it is continually explicated in time.
>
> However — and **this is vital — truth never ceases to be the truth and never contradicts itself**:  one truth does not abolish another truth — nor does it contradict a truth already revealed.
>
> For this reason the Magisterium of the Church teaches us, with ever greater clarity — and as the need arises —  what the Holy Ghost would further reveal (St. John 15.26; St. John 16.13) — which is and must be completely consistent with what has been already revealed. More remains true to be said than what has already been said until the **fullness of truth** culminates in the blinding reality of the Parousia, or the Second Coming of Christ, when this world will pass away, and all within it. Only then will the fullness of truth be realized, for no more could possibly be said of, predicated of, what has reached its culmination in time and passed into eternity.
>
> Of one thing we are certain: **what the Holy Ghost will yet reveal to us will not abolish or contradict** what He has already taught us, revealed to His Church in Holy Scripture and in the Sacred Deposit of Faith of 2000 years. God, Who is Truth, cannot contradict Himself. - [The Fullness of Truth and the Magisterium of the Holy Catholic Church](http://www.boston-catholic-journal.com/the-fullness-of-truth-and-the-magisterium-of-the-holy-catholic-church.htm)

Obviously the Eastern Orthodox Churches are not in full communion with the Holy Catholic Church and as such we will always be disagreements between us until that day when true unity has been achieved. I believe it will happen, but no one knows when.